# Who is the acting Minister of Defence of Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, government, succession

The Russian Minister of Defence Sergei Shoigu has apparently had some health mishaps and hasn't been able to work for a month or more by now. In my country at the beginning of any absences of ministers there's a short ruling announced that such and such (usually another minister) is taking on the duties. I was not able to find anything about how that's handled in the Russian cabinet or this case specifically.

1. Has there been any announcement about who's doing the job now?
2. If not, what is the normal *line of succession* for Russian ministers? Who *should* be doing the job?

Comment: He was apparently seen at the end of March https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/24/europe/russia-sergei-shoigu-health-intl/index.html but it's apparently not clear when the footage was shot.

Answer (score 11):

General of the Army S. K. Shoigu [remains the Minister of Defense](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/24/europe/russia-sergei-shoigu-health-intl/index.html) despite a temporary health condition, according to official sources as of [the last available media report I could locate on March 27, 2022](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/24/europe/russia-sergei-shoigu-health-intl/index.html) (Reuters [confirms this as of April 19, 2022](https://news.yahoo.com/russia-methodically-carrying-plan-eastern-121723641.html)).

The person [second in command to the Minister of Defense in Russia](https://military-history.fandom.com/wiki/Ministry_of_Defence_(Russia)) is the Chief of the General Staff a.k.a. 1st Deputy Minister of Defense. This is [General of the Army Valery Gerasimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_of_the_General_Staff_(Russia)). As such, he would have the authority to direct the Russian Ministry of Defense in most respects when the Minister himself is temporarily unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Sergei Shoigu was and, as of today, still remains at his current position: https://news.yahoo.com/amphtml/russia-methodically-carrying-plan-eastern-121723641.html .
The rumors of his death are somewhat exaggerated.